# What is the difference between "Game", "Screen" and "ApplicationAdapter" in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

In tutorials sometimes people use "extends Game", sometimes "implements Screen" and i have auto-generated "extends ApplicationAdapter". What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ApplicationAdapter` allows you to create a listener, but not being forced to implement every method. If you're familiar with Swing, check out `KeyAdapter`, it's the same idea.

An `ApplicationListener` allows you to handle application events. This allows you to execute code during certain events within the application life-cycle (such as destroy).

> An ApplicationListener is called when the Application is created, resumed, rendering, paused or destroyed. All methods are called in a thread that has the OpenGL context current. You can thus safely create and manipulate graphics resources.

A `Game` is an `ApplicationListener` that supports multiple screens. You can create multiple screens and switch between em using `setScreen`.

> An ApplicationListener that delegates to a Screen. This allows an application to easily have multiple screens.

A `Screen` is exactly what it sounds like; it's what will be displayed at that given time. Maybe it's a main menu, maybe it's the actual game.

> Represents one of many application screens, such as a main menu, a settings menu, the game screen and so on.

It's recommended you use the `Game` class for the base of your game, then create multiple `Screen` instances of the different possible game states you will have.

Comment: Clear answer, thanks! 
There's also this page from the doc that should help: https://libgdx.com/wiki/app/the-life-cycle