# extends Game / extends ApplicationAdapter - why libgdx defaults to ApplicationAdapter?

Tags: java, libgdx, extends

I was reading the comments on this question and answer: [What is the difference between "Game", "Screen" and "ApplicationAdapter" in libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222541/what-is-the-difference-between-game-screen-and-applicationadapter-in-libg)

It helped me understand it a lot. But what I don't get is why does LibGDX default project extend ApplicationAdapter, when it is recommended to extend Game 
(and of course virtually all games are going to have multiple screen states and LibGDX is specifically for games.

Comment: It's arbitrary. Game is not necessarily recommended. It's just one way of doing things. I don't use Game because I like to have fancier transitions than fade to black, which is the best you can do with Screens.

Comment: OK Thanks. I'm still learning the basics of how to lay out my classes and switch between gamestates in an organised manner. So for now I guess just extend Game and learn to use Screens until I find it limiting me.